# While performing ghusl( while I was washing my right side) I bymistakely touched my hair. Does that void my ghusl?. I am a male

Tags: ghusl

While performing ghusl I bymistakely touched my hair while I was cleaning my right side of the body, does that void my ghusl, and I am a male. And I have a doubt that my hand touched a piece of wood in the bathroom. I am having doubts. Thankyou for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
Of course not. Islam is meant to be taken at ease. There are only certain items that invalidate ghusl and wudu, and this is not one of them.
It is typically performed in preparation for formal prayers (salah or salat), particularly before handling and reading the Quran. Activities that invalidate wudu include urination, defecation, flatulence, deep sleep, light bleeding and sexual intercourse.
hope this helps! :)
-Michelle

Comment: So while performing ghusl you touched your hair bymistakely it does not void my ghusl right?

Comment: And while performing wudu for ghusl and you touched a piece of wudu bymistakely in your bathroom (don't know if it's pure or Impure) does this invalidate my wudu? and should I repeat ghusl all over again.??